# Does limiting the number of PIDs on an OBDII Live Scan increase the sampling rate?

Tags: obd-ii, scan-tool

I was messing around with the live scan settings on my BlueDriver OBDII scanner and I checked another PID box and got this message:

> To provide the best quality of data, we recommend logging no more than
>   5 live sources at once.

[image: PID count quality warning message]

I checked my data log after about a minute of recording live data and my time points were spaced as follows with uniform spacing of 4.3 s:

```
Time (s)
0.0
4.3
8.6
12.9
17.2
21.5
25.8
30.1
34.4
38.7
43.0
47.3
51.6
55.9
60.2
64.5
```

I was recording with 26 PIDS at the time. I'll try experimenting tomorrow with a single pid and with a pair and so forth and see what happens to my time delta. But my question is whether or not there is a tradeoff between sampling rate and PID count? What determines the sampling rate, is it my ECU, my OBDII scanner, the number of PIDs I'm looking up?

I'm just not sure what the message is referring to with "quality" precisely.

EDIT: just rescanned a live session this morning and dropped the PID count down to 5; the sampling interval was measured at 0.5s between data points for like 5 minutes of recording.

Comment: The bus speed?...